# How to keep a video playing between beamer frames?

Tags: beamer, overlays, multimedia, video

I am currently creating a presentation where in a specific section I want to introduce a specific problem.
I do it by adding a video playing on the background and updating `\minipage` contents on the right side of the video.

I can include a video in my presentation without problems using `\usepackage{multimedia}` and the `\movie` command.

See the extracted part of my code below (hope it works I did not try it):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{frame}{Pulling hose problem}
  \begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
      \movie[autostart,loop,continue]{
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{anImage.png}
      }{aMovie.mpg}

    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}  \hfill
%
\only<1>{
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \textbf{\color{txtcolor2} Setup :}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item HRP-2 humanoid robot
      \item rigid, \emph{empty} fire hoze
      \item motion capture system
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
}
%
\only<2>{
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \textbf{\color{txtcolor2} Major technical issues while}
    \begin{itemize}


    \item \textbf{\color{txtcolor2} pulling :}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Important drift
      \item Robot less balanced
    \end{itemize}

    \item \textbf{\color{txtcolor2} picking :}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Self-collision
        \item Joint limit
        \item Balance
      \end{itemize}

    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
}
%
\only<3>{
  \begin{minipage}{0.39\textwidth}
    \textbf{\color{txtcolor2} Objectives :}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Pick up a rigid fire hose
      \item Pull it toward a desired position
    \end{itemize}
    \vspace*{0.7cm}
  \end{minipage}
}
%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem here is that Beamer will create several slides with the `only<>` instruction.
And the video will start again form time `0` each time I update the `only<>` part of the slide.

The question is :
Is there a way to keep the video playing while updating the slide?

I have been circling around with google I found only topics about embedded video in slide....
If someone knows if it is possible or not possible please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I think, keep the video playing will conceptional not be possible, as every overlay is an individual page in the pdf. However you could play a segment of the video in each overlay. So if for example the first frame should show the first minute and the second the second minute:

- the time range per overlay can be specified with `start=0s,duration=60s`
- to automatically switch slides `\animate<1-2> \transduration<1-2>{60.0}`

(Untested due to missing video file)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Pulling hose problem}
        \animate<1-2>%
        \transduration<1-2>{60.0}%

        \begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
            \centering
            \only<1>{
                \movie[autostart,loop,continue,start=0s,duration=60s ]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{anImage.png}}{aMovie.mpg}
            }
            \only<2>{
                \movie[autostart,loop,continue,start=60s,duration=60s ]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{anImage.png}}{aMovie.mpg}
            }
        \end{minipage}  
        \hfill
        %
        \only<1>{
            \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                1   
            \end{minipage}
        }
        \only<2>{
            \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                2   
            \end{minipage}
        }

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, however I have troubleshooting with the "autostart" which is not working so well.

Comment: @MaximilienNaveau Can you be a bit more specific about "not working so well"? [As I said, I have not tested myself]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, however I have troubleshooting with the "autostart" which is not working so well.
I wanted to point out that in media9 (which I thought was embedded inside the beamer package now) it is possible to make the video continue though there is a slide change.
So with this functionality I thought it might be possible to keep the video playing with an overlay.
Moreover sound can be keept through slide change so I thought that the video could as well...

Comment: The not working so well means that it does not work at all, I am guessing it is because of the old version of Okular I am using (Ubuntu12.04 lts)